# Android full screen animation, what's the best way?

Tags: android

Wanted to ask what's the best way to play a full-screen animation on android, say a few hundred frames?

I think it too short for putting it into a movie and messing with videoview. So I guess maybe just rendering each frame as a separate PNG file and having an imageView change its picture by a timer, what do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use 30 frames/second will be efficient and very useful to you

Comment: you mean with imageview view and switching pngs 30 times per sec. ?

Comment: You want to create the animation png all same images(same image with different animation) in same frame and you want run the same frame where you  need that image to be animation

Comment: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android19Animation.php check this for your reference